# How can I use DropBox as a simple backup?

Tags: backup, dropbox

I'd like to use my Dropbox account to backup my "Documents" folder, without running the risk of deleting something on Dropbox and my files being deleted on my computer. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Does it have to be DropBox? I use DropBox to synchronise files across computers quickly, but [SpiderOak](https://spideroak.com/) to back up (it can also sync files, but a bit slower than DropBox).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First off, you should be aware that you can [recover deleted files from Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/help/296/en). Also, Dropbox keeps a version history of your files. So you don't need to worry about accidentally deleting files from your Dropbox folder.

---

Backing up to your Dropbox folder is easy. Just use any back up tool, and set the destination to your Dropbox folder.

Here's how to do it with Ubuntu's [Backup tool [image: Install deja-dup]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/deja-dup) that comes with Ubuntu by default:

- Launch "Backup".
- Click the "Storage" tab.
- Under Backup location, choose your Dropbox folder.

You can also use other backup tools like [rsync [image: Install rsync]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/rsync).

---

Another method to back up files automatically is to create a **symlink** in your Dropbox directory, pointing to directories you want to back up.

For example, this will include your Documents folder in your Dropbox storage automatically:

```
cd ~/Dropbox
ln -s ~/Documents Documents
```

Comment: +1 for symlink way to do that for specific folder

Comment: I understand that Dropbox stopped supporting symlinks.

Answer (score 7):

You could turn Documents into a symbolic link that points to Dropbox, or use a 'backup' program like rsync to mirror the files.

Answer (score 0):

Use restic with rclone. (Not sure this counts as simple, but it works.)

1. Install [rclone](https://rclone.org/) and set up a Dropbox remote by following the [configuration instructions](https://rclone.org/dropbox/). Here the remote is called "remote".
2. Install [restic](https://restic.net/) and create a remote repository using rclone and the Dropbox remote created in step 1:

```
$ restic -r rclone:remote:path/to/restic-repo init
```

3. Back up a directory:

```
$ restic -r rclone:remote:path/to/restic-repo backup /somedir
```

You can then use a scheduler such as cron or systemd to repeat the backup periodically.