# How can I use Dropbox as a backup without syncing the backup to my harddrive?

Tags: 12.04, backup, dropbox, deja-dup

I use Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit. I read this link: "[How can I use DropBox as a simple backup?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/226131/how-can-i-use-dropbox-as-a-simple-backup)" which suggests to backup using deja-dup to the Dropbox folder. However, if I would do this, the backups will also be placed on my local harddrive, which takes up a lot of space. If I unsync the specific dropbox folder, I cannot access it anymore from Nautilus. Importing  a manually created .tar file (+/- 50 Gb) to the unsynced Dropbox folder using the Dropbox Web application is very slow. Does anybody have a good solution for this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

One option I can think of, perhaps is to use the Dropbox API, and a carefully crafted `curl` command to send your file up to your dropbox. This will allow you to send the file up, without needing to keep it synced on your workstation.

See this API command: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#files_put